# Is $ \{ x+xi \ | \ x \in R \}$ isomorphic to a straight line through the origin in $R^2$?

Tags: group-isomorphism

Is  $ \{ x+xi \ | \ x \in R \}$ isomorphic to a straight line through the origin in $R^2$?  (where, $i^2=-1$)

Comment: Lines in the complex plane have the form $a+bt$ where $a,b \in \mathbb C$ are fixed points and $t \in \mathbb R$.  You can write your set as $0 + (1+i)x$, $x \in \mathbb R$, so yes, that set is a line in the complex plane.  There should be an obvious correspondence with a line in the real plane.

Comment: @UmbertoP. so i would be right in saying $\{ x+xi \ | \ x \in R \}  \cong  \{ y \ | \ y=x, x \in R \} $?

Comment: I think $\{(x,y) \mid y=x, x \in R\}$ would be more accurate.